# Viewing incoming ping on windows server

Tags: windows, ping, netstat

I'm trying to see the results of an incoming ping on a target windows machine. This is needed to verify that the ping, which is running in a background thread, is being sent from the originator.

I have tried netstat to no avail. Are there any other approaches I could try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ping is an ICMP packet and doesn't create a TCP connection (hence you won't see it in `netstat`). On Linux, I'd add a rule to the firewall.

The most simple solution for your case might be to open a connection and close it. That will add it to the output of `netstat` with `WAIT_CLOSE`.

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron Digulla already noted, ping is ICMP. This also means the originator even less trustable then with TCP; there's no SYN/ACK handshake. You just get an IP packet on your host, and you have to trust the header fields. Anyone can spoof those header fields, with almost no restrictions (It might be a bit challenging to get an IP claiming to come from 127.0.0.1 past a router)

Therefore, ICMP is not suitabel for verification tasks. You need a challenge/response protocol. TCP works reasoanbly well as long as you can trust the network but not necessarily all hosts on it (a reasonable assumption for the Internet. Not strong enough for financial transactions, which is why they use SSL)